# SQL Query to export rows by date to own CSV

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, export-to-csv

I need to export multiple rows containing a date, and for a specific date range, to their own csv file.

Example data:

```
Col1.       Col2.        Col3.       Col4.
2/15/2014   Building #   Type A      14
2/15/2014   Building #   Type A      3
2/16/2014   Building #   Type A      12
```

Desired Output:

**Two seperate CSV files**

Sheet 1 "2_15_2014.csv"

```
Col1.       Col2.        Col3.       Col4.
2/15/2014   Building #   Type A      14
2/15/2014   Building #   Type A      3
```

Sheet 1 "2_16_2014.csv"

```
Col1.       Col2.        Col3.       Col4.
2/16/2014   Building #   Type A      12
```

Comment: Can you try a loop that checks for a new date and creates a new csv file each time it finds one?

Comment: How to do this depends a lot on what database you are using specifically, can you specify?

Comment: MySQL database. Sorry for the unclarity.

Comment: Is your Col1 a DATE column or just VARCHAR?

Comment: Col1 could be either. I can adjust it if needed.

Comment: Fire up the query with an appropriate WHERE clause for the first date in phpMyAdmin and use the `Export` button to export as CSV, then do the same with the second one. If you've got a lot of those I would recommend using a script, i.e. PHP.